Differential input resistance of non-symmetric circuits
In Sedra and Smith (7th edition, section 2.4.1) when building up to an instrumentation amplifier there is discussion of how to use a single op-amp (differential input, single-ended output) to implement a differential amplifier (figure 2.16 below) with infinite common-mode rejection, i.e. the output can be expressed as $$V_O=A(V_{I2}-V_{I1})$$
if one chooses the resistor values such that \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}=\frac{R_4}{R_3}\$. The example also shows how, if one chooses \$R_3=R_1,\ R_4=R_2\$ and applies an input voltage as show in figure 2.19 (below), one can define the differential input resistance as \$R_{id}=2R_1\$. However, this feels awkward to me for a couple reasons.
The way the differential voltage is being applied in Fig. 2.19 treats the circuit as a two-port where the input doesn't have a terminal in common with the output, which is possible; but I think a practical implementation of the circuit would be better modeled (in the differential mode) like in the below schematic, with an ac-ground where the shared common-mode level bias would be. Under this condition, the currents through the two \$R_1\$ resistors are actually not equal since the op-amp input terminals are not at 0, as the circuit is asymmetric (even though there is no common mode gain).
Can the differential input resistance be meaningfully defined in this case?
I assume the model of Fig. 2.19 was chosen in order to compare later to the input resistance of the instrumentation amplifier, but is there any other reason it makes good sense for this circuit on its own? The amplifier is in general a three-port, not a two-port.




The answer is yes, please come up with an analytical solution, think about what happens if Vxn=Vxp which happens when the op amp is 1)Closed loop 2) steady state.

Assuming that vid != 0, when Vxm=Vxp=r2/(r1+r2)*vid/2, the currents across the input resistors are not equal, and so there isn't a unique ratio for vid/(input current), which is what makes me unsure that "differential input resistance" can be meaningfully defined as opposed to input resistance on a single side, which can clearly be defined uniquely.

What is the current across the resistors?

The current through the resistor connected to positive input is vid/2/(r1+r2) while the magnitude of the current through the resistor connected to negative input is vid/2/r1*(r1+2*r2)/(r1+r2). These match up with the simulation results for the given schematic, which are 454 uA and 9.55 mA, respectively. So since the current through each of these resistors are not equal I don't see how the differential input resistance can be defined. This is in contrast to Fig. 2.19, which necessarily has equal currents through the resistors.
